# CSS - how to put a opacity border to an input?

Tags: css

I want to make a border with opacity ( transparent border ) to an input but i would like that works also in IE7+

thanks

Comment: what is your problem? what have you tried?

Comment: juste that the transparent border can work in IE7+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have opacity on a boarder, you need to use the RGBA color scheme, otherwise the entire element takes on the opacity setting.

```
border-color:rgba(255,0,0,.1)
```

IE7 does not support the RGBA color scheme, neither does IE8. You'll have to make the border solid for these browsers, or try using [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) to generate a polyfill.

See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-opacity

Comment: he talks about transparent border, so maybe `border-color:transparent;` might be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, go for [CSS3 border image](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/):

`border-image: url(border.png) 27 27 27 27 round round;`

In this case using 'png 24-bit' with opacity is your solution.